# How to catch exceptions from the jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-integration

Is it possible to catch exceptions from the `jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter` (e.g. problem with database during query execution)?
E.g. in the `http-outbound-gateway` it possible to use error handler declared with `error-handler` attribute.
Thanx in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter` is fully based on the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` and its `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` wrapper for "hard" polling logic.

I'm pretty sure you have provided a `<poller>` configuration for the mentioned `jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter` or globally.

That one has this option:

```
   <xsd:attribute name="error-channel" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
                Identifies channel that error messages will be sent to if a failure occurs in this
                poller's invocation. To completely suppress Exceptions, provide a
                reference to the "nullChannel" here.
            ]]></xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

So, when there is some error during polling DB, it is going to be wrapped to an `ErrorMessage` and be sent to a configured `error-channel`. If it is not provided, a global `errorChannel` bean is going to be used.

See Error Handling chapter in the Reference Manual for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: Artem, thank you for the clarification: the mechanism is clear. 
This is what was needed!